# Rider does not detect UnitTest

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have recently started to use the Rider IDE from JetBrains for my projects. I faced an issue when one day after opening the solution, the IDE suddenly could not recognize any of test cases in the solution. Before all the test cases were OK.

I have checked the imports and tried restarting Rider and my PC, however, the problem is still present.

Has someone solved the same issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JetBrains Rider unable to detect UnitTests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67186254/jetbrains-rider-unable-to-detect-unittests)

Comment: Or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77612275/run-see-nunit4-in-rider